# Azure active directory tree structure

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Azure active directory to build a test directory, with tree structure (groups, users, subgroups, etc.). If we need to fetch the whole thing / tree, how can I get the first level elements (groups / users) with the Azure Graph Api ?

Seems that a possible way is to loop fetch all members of existing groups, and exclude users/groups which are not in the member collection. But this solution does not scale well when dealing with large size directory.

I've tested `/groups` and `/users` endpoints, but all users / groups will be returned without their level information (its parent groups / subgroups).

I've also tried `<parentId>/members` api, but what parent id should i
use here in order to fetch all first level members ?

I'm wondering whether it's possible to do this (easily) with the acutal azure graph api...

Thanks for help.